# Rails security validations in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm wondering if there is a best way to achieve this the rail way in my controller :

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  # you can only view a public article or your own articles.
  @article = nil unless @article.public? || @article.owner?(current_user)
end

def edit
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  # you can only edit your own articles
  @article = nil unless @article.owner?(current_user)
end
```

I have a couple validations like this in my application and I can clearly see it's easy to miss one and give access to something that you should not!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not the Rails way. one of the rails principles is take all the object manipulation on Model layer. Controllers mostly cares about overall authorizations/authentication/cache invalidation/cookie and sessions settings.

you can use **associations** and **scope**

```
class ArticlesControllers << ApplicationsController

  def show
    @article = current_user.articles.public.find(params[:id])
  end

end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :public, :where('public').is('true')

end
```

Comment: That's not quite what I was looking for, but that's a start. This is a better way to do it, but It will get me my OWN and PUBLIC articles, where I meant to have either a public article or my own article.

Comment: Maybe something like "Article.public.find(params[:id]) || current_user.articles.find(params[:id])" would work?

Comment: you better to wrap it into a model's method. Pass current_user as a params and move the conditional expression into the method

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I'd use [CanCan](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan).

```
can :read, Article, public: true
can :manage, Article, owner_id: user.id
```